# NUXT - Reuse view from default.vue in 3 pages

Tags: forms, architecture, tabs, nuxt.js

In Nuxt I have 3 pages (index, login and register) that needs to show the same structure, the code above.
It's a form with tabs. then in the  tag it's were I show some diferences.
I decided to put that code in the default.vue file.
But now, I have  more pages were I don't need to show the "forms" class and the tabs.
Any suggestion about how can I achieve it?
Thank you

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container is-fluid">
      <navbar></navbar>
      <div class="places">
        <div class="structure">
          <div class="forms">
            <div class="tabs help-tabs">
              <ul class="tab_title">
                <li :class="[tab === 'register' ? 'is-active' : '']">
                  <a @click="tab='register'">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li
                  :class="[tab === 'login' ? 'is-active' : '']"
                  @click="goToRoute('login')">
                  <a @click="tab = 'login'">Login</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <nuxt />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either create a second `layout` beside the `default.vue` and use it only for these routes (index, login and register) so you have:

1. `auth.vue` for index, login and register pages
2. `default.vue` for all other pages

You could then specify which layout you want to use in the page file directly like [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-layout)

```
export default {
  layout: 'auth',
}
```

Or you stick to using one single layout (`default.vue`) and create a component (eg. tab component) which you then display on all 3 of those routes.